# Who are the two cloaked figures in Snoke's throne room?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, snoke, first-order

In the Last Jedi I recall in the first scene where Snoke's throne room is shown, there are two cloaked figures in the background working on a device. From what I could tell, the figures were remarkably similar in appearance to Jawas.

[image]

However, I think this is not the case as the cloaked figures in TLJ seemed to be of taller stature than Jawas. So what are these beings? And why would they be used to service equipment instead of some other First Order technician?

Comment: They're not cloaked figures, its the stand for snoke's telescope (from what i can see.)

Comment: @Brickgunner I'm certain they are not part of the stand for the telescope because in a later scene when Rey is looking through it the figures are not in the throne room.

Comment: Railings in some places and not in others. Better than previous incarnations? Or horrible because of lack of consistency?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are identified in the film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) as Snoke's "Attendants".

We also get a little bit of back-story. Apparently they were instrumental in helping the fleeing Imperial fleet to escape the newly resurgent Galactic Republic after their defeat at Jakku. This was when they apparently came under the influence of Snoke and the First Order.

> **ATTENDANTS**
>
> *Snoke's retinue includes mute alien navigators who originated in the
>   Unknown Regions. Were it not for the ancient hyperspace trails blazed
>   by these towering servants, the Imperial survivors who fled into this
>   uncharted realm would certainly have perished. These navigators
>   designed and operate the oculus viewing scope in Snoke's throne room.*

and

> - "*Englarged brains can process multi-dimensional calculations*"
> - "*Amplification lenses assist naturally weak eyes*"

[image]

Comment: And they stopped attending when Snoke became half the man he used to be?

Comment: They sound like a nod to Guild Navigators.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai "Traveling through hyperspace ain't like dusting crops, Muad'Dib!"